# Transformar una variable string en el nombre de un archivo en python

Tags: python, pygame

Según una selección que va haciendo el usuario se van almacenando datos en un array, los junto con un join para transformarlo en un nombre que coincide con el nombre de uno de los archivos disponibles y después quiero que se muestre:

```
if x > 400 and x < 535 and y > 100 and y < 209:
 seleccion[1] = "V"
 imgActual = mostrar.join(seleccion)
 ventana.blit(imgActual,(100,100))
```

El proble es que cuando hace el blit sale este error: "    ventana.blit(imgActual,(100,100))
TypeError: argument 1 must be pygame.Surface, not str"

Comment: No se de Pygame, pero por el error creo que `.blit` no espera la ruta de la imagen sino un objeto `Surface` que contenga esa textura. Échale un vistazo a la documentación de Pygame que seguro que está

Answer (score 2):

El error deja ver que está pasando:

> ventana.blit(imgActual, (100,100)) ErrorDeTipo: el argumento 1 debe ser `pygame.Surface`, no `str`

Es decir, `blit` necesita recibir una instancia de [`pygame.Surface`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html) y le estás pasando una mera cadena de texto, por mucho que esta sea una ruta válida a una imagen. Si tu imagen ees un archivo en disco, debes cargarla primero con [`pygame.image.load`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/image.html), lo cual genera una `Surface` que si puedes pasar a `blit`:

```
import pygame

if 400 < x < 535 and 100 < y < 209:
    seleccion[1] = "V"
    nombre_img_actual = mostrar.join(seleccion)
    img_actual = pygame.image.load(nombre_img_actual)
    ventana.blit(img_actual, (100, 100))
```

Ten en cuenta que leer el archivo desde el disco y cargar la imagen en memoria tiene un costo importante. Si vas a mostrar las imagenes repetidamente deberías cargarlas en memoria desde el inicio, almacenar las surfaces en un diccionario con el nombre como clave por ejemplo (por ejemplo) y limitarte a dibujarla cuando se precise obteniendo su referencia del diccionario.